# Einstein's "answers have changed"

Tags: einstein, physicists

I remember first seeing this anecdote a few years ago in a newspaper article, now I am seeing more frequently in motivational content over the internet, every time with very few additional details. The story goes as follow:

While in Princeton or Oxford University, a graduate assistant or a teacher asked Albert Einstein why did he gave his (sometimes 2nd year graduate) students the same exam as last year. Einstein answered that he was not worried, "it is exactly the same, well the answers have changed [since]".

As with many of Einstein's quotes, this narration seems fabricated. Is there any source for this quote/story? Could it be a true story wrongly misattributed to Einstein? Do we know who could be the assistant/professor? What were the facts that had changed? Was he teaching optics, dynamics, atomic physics or cosmology (or all of the above)?

So far, the oldest source I have found might be (American religion author) John Bytheway's 1999 *What I Wish I'd Known When I Was Single*, a self-help book (he mentions Princeton). See also Paul Rulken's 2014 TEDxTalk ["Why the majority is always wrong"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNGFep6rncY&ab_channel=TEDxTalks). The Princeton/Oxford fact narrows this event down to 1931-1939 (Rulken says 1932).

Comment: To begin with, I don't think Einstein ever taught courses to university students:-) And surely he did not teach the same course two years in row.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko maybe some advanced topical course? But then why do it two years in a row...

Comment: Indeed, the Wikipedia article shows that he taught in several universities in  1909-13.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko which seems to not be the right period.